# FreeTDS and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, freetds

I'm getting this when trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 using Moodle:

> 4004: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot
>   be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7
>   or earlier.

I changed the version to 8.0 in the ini file, but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Moodle doc](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP):

> The SQL Server complaining that it doesn't support pure Unicode via
>   TDS or older versions of ODBC. Microsoft has deprecated DB-Library a
>   long ago, in favor of ODBC, OLE DB, or SQL Native Client. Many new
>   features of SQL 2005 aren't accessible via DB-Library so if you need
>   them, you could have to switch away from tools based on TDS and
>   DB-Library :(

Answer (score 0):

My config file was messed up. I was not using version 8.0 of TDS. I have explicitly set it to use 8.0. Since I fixed that, everything works fine.